# Getting ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies error occasionally (.Net Core 3.0)

Tags: iis, hosting, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to host my ASP.Net Core 3.0 application on my server and localhost. But I get this error occasionally in both of them. When I get this error, I change the project's deploy configuration like; if it is self-contained, I change it to Framework-Dependent or if it is framework-dependent, I change it to self-contained. And it is working. But I can't do that on production time. What if I get this error when I deliver the app to customer. So I need a permanent solution.

I publish application via Visual Studio 2019.

```
Publish method: FileSystem
Configuration: Debug or Release
Target Framework: netcoreapp3.0
Deployment Mode: SelfContained or Framework-Dependent
Target Runtime : win-x64
Delete all existing files prior to publish checked.
```

I checked a solution which says delete spaces in project id, But I have not a project that has a space in project id.

Event Logger Messages;

Unable to locate application dependencies. Ensure that the versions of Microsoft.NetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App targeted by the application are installed.

Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
Could not resolve CoreCLR path. For more details, enable tracing by setting COREHOST_TRACE environment variable to 1.

But I have aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll in my published folder.

Comment: Could you please tell me what your application's Deployment Mode now? Self-contained or Framework-Dependent? If you choose Framework-Dependent, you must install the asp.net core 3.0 runtime in your server.

Comment: I installed Hosting Bundle. It is working as both of them. But after new publish, occasionally I get this  ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies error. When I get this error, I change the deployment mode and I publish it again and it is working again. As I said, I need a permanent solution.